# Anchor link/ section from another page doesn't work because of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem here about anchor link/section. So i have this index.html and rooms.html

Everything's working fine on the index.html, every single anchor link is working  (jump to certain section)

The problem is, in my rooms.html it doesn't work. i tried to declare a link to every section of the index.html ( you can see it in the code). But none are working.

Until i delete the jQuery script declaration and suddenly the anchor link is working. So my question is, how do i fix this? because i need jQuery on my page

Many thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: There is a Jquery error on your code `TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined` rooms.html line:42. Since it prevents the default anchor tag behaviour/action link doesn't redirect into index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have the following function:

```
 $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== ""){
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();
```

Which tried to smoothscroll external links too, but that wouldnt work. You will need to rethink your smoothscrolling implementation to do something like search for an anchor tag whose href begins with '#'.

Answer (score 2):

Read line 33, in your index.html. The scrip comment says "this will prevent default behavior", eg. it won't work properly. What I would do is have your jQuery scrolling script only target specific anchors on the page with the purpose of scrolling. For example, all the ones that you want to smooth scroll, give them a class of .smooth-scroll and target that class in your jQuery instead. Chances are though, you're gonna have to rethink the way you do the smoothScrolling

Answer (score 0):

Try to add: rel="external" to the a tag. If this doesn't help try instead to replace it with data-ajax="false" .